# VirtualBox VM screen size not changing

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I just created a Kali VM in VirtualBox 6.1.  My VM's display settings are set to 256 MB video memory, one monitor, and a scale factor of 100%.

When the VM starts, the display window is very small.  When I switch to full screen mode (CMD+F on my Mac), everything stays the same size but the rest of my screen is filled up with black.

If it helps, my Macbook has 1.5 GB of video memory.

EDIT:

I also have an Ubuntu 20.04 VM running on the same host.  It has the same display settings and its full screen capability works perfectly.

Comment: I have a Kali machine in VMware. I saw this early on.  Try updating Kali to the current version. If you are trying to run full screen, try running in a windowed environment. Try updating the video drivers on the host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was merely an issue of adjusting the display resolution within Kali itself.